# Reversing and Shifting

Tags: code-golf, string

<sup>[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/18384/78850)</sup>

*Adapted from exercise 8 of [100 little Keg exercises](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/100-Little-Keg-Exercises)*

String manipulation is a very important part of any programming language. Consequently, that is what this challenge is about.

### The Challenge

I want you to write a program that:

- Takes a series of characters as input and,
- Then takes another input (integer/letter) (we'll call this `instruction`) and,
- Takes a single integer (we'll call this `times`) as the last input and then,
- If `instruction` is equal to the letter `R`:

  - Reverse the string `times` times.
- Otherwise, if `instruction` is equal to the letter `l`:

  - Shift the string left `times` times
- Otherwise, for all other values of `instruction`:

  - Shift the string right `times` times

### Test Cases

```
String, Instruction, Times -> Output
"Howdy!", R, 1 -> "!ydwoH"
"elloH", r, 1 -> "Hello"
"tedShif", l, 3 -> "Shifted"
"sn't it?Amazing, i", l, 8 -> "Amazing, isn't it?"
```

### Rules

- Input can be taken as *any* convenient format... if a list of three items works best for you, take the input as a list. If newline-separated input is how you choose to work, go ahead and use newline-separated input.
- The string, instruction and times integer can be taken in any order
- Output is also to be given in any convenient format.
- The input string will *not* contain newlines, nor unprintable ascii characters.
- You can substitute `R` and `l` for any other two characters, as long as you specify what the two characters are
- All instructions are case sensitive. In other words, only input of `R` should reverse the string, not `r`.
- The magnitude of a shift will always be less than the length of the string
- The `times` integer is a positive integer (i.e. \$ n > 0 \$)

### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the fewest bytes wins.

Comment: May we assume the magnitude of a shift is less than the length of the string?

Comment: Yes, you may indeed make that assumption.

Comment: And that the integer given will always be non-negative?

Comment: _reverse the stack_ you mean _string_, right?

Comment: May the input requires `R`everse the string 2 times?

Comment: @tsh yes, the input could possibly be reversed 2 times

Comment: It's a crime that there's no Keg answer here.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 65 bytes

```python
lambda s,i,t:[s[(n:=[-t,t][i=='l']):]+s[:n],s[::(-1)**t]][i=='R']
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcnBCgIhFEDRfV8hbtTJWdRsQvAnZmsujDQFc@T5CPp6M4KINndxT31i3MpyqtCDPvfs7perI00mico0w4vSZkaJ1iStWWZWKLtvRhUrRxWfD2Ka0H54ZbZXSAV54BTSLSJpMQWkklAYOQqx@3r24YfzP4N/eGju/ek6sgjRXw)

Abuses the de-facto ternary statement `[a,b][condition]`.

- If `i=='R'`:

  - Return the string, read with step `(-1)**t`. This is `-1` (reversed) for odd `t` and `1` (not reversed) for even `t`.
- Else:

  - Let `n` be `[-t,t][i=='l']`. This is `t` when left-shifting and `-t` otherwise (right-shifting).
  - Return the string, spliced accordingly: `s[n:] + s[:n]`. Thanks to Python's negative indexing, this works like a charm for both cases.

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Full program. Prompts for the string, then `times`, then `instruction`:

- `+` for reversal
- `1` for left shift
- any other character for right shift

```apl
(⍎⍕⊃¯1,⍨⍞∩'+1')⌽⍣⎕⊢⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94L/Go96@R71TH3U1H1pvqPOod8Wj3nmPOlaqaxuqaz7q2fuod/GjPqDsIqAwSMN/BTAo4PLIL0@pVOQy5NLmggml5uTkewBFiuAiJakpwRmZaVzGQFGYWHGeeolCZom9Y25iVWZeuo5CJpcFlyEA)

`⍞` prompt for string

`⊢` on that, do the following:

`⎕` prompt for `times`

`(`…`)⌽⍣` apply the `⌽` function that many times, with the following to its left:

`∩'+1'` intersection of the following and `"+1"`:

`⍞` prompt for `instruction`

`¯1,⍨` append negative one

`⊃` pick the first one

`⍕` stringify

`⍎` evaluate (gives `1` or `-1` or the complex conjugate function `+`)

The function `⌽` does a:

- left shift if it has `1` on its left
- right shift if it has `-1` on its left
- reversal if it has any function on its left

`+` negates the imaginary part of its argument but strings have no imaginary parts, so it does nothing

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 67 bytes

```python
lambda s,t,i:[s[t:]+s[:t],s[::1-t%2*2],s[-t:]+s[:-t]]['lR'.find(i)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYlBDsIgEADP@oq9GFpdTMQbiZ/winugInYt0gb24uuxJl4mmZnlI@OcTYuXW0v@PQQPFQXZuurE0qE6K4Qr7UnLzuzNT/T/aCFyKl3VMXIOHffU4lyAgTOosna73SyFswAjxE754R4e8Tnya0oKz8h9@wI)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```ruby
->s,c,n{c==?R?[s,s.reverse][n%2]:s.chars.rotate(c==?l?n:-n)*''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBb4IwFIDv/IpnxwK4UqPuYEwq2Y2zOyIxDIo0qWVp6wgz7q@zB8Z4aJt@3/eeuXz1Q80PQ7yztKT6WnKe7JPMUsuM@BHGijzTr6t8a1nZFAZp6wonwrFTid7GOpoHwW3oGqkEnISzHoB/BP4HCxKyeUQohCzC61C9RRDv4E4XmBlhgUOd@UsK/grPmrn2KHNU3xdnR0@B4MjLdUo5@O834gldDSRtu6qf4fI9heW0dtZXXZsSjwil8KVgHiYdCQonqs9G1qgUhfWkxj9ilFYHDqRLPs7Fr9QnCvLebabuSR8d@Qc)

An anonymous lambda that takes 3 arguments. If the instruction is `R`, it returns the original or the reversed version based on whether `n` is even or odd. Otherwise, it converts the string into a character array and `rotate`s that left or right based on the instruction specified (Ruby rotates left if the argument provided is positive) the joins the char array back together into a string using `*''`.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
²³F1¹QiRë0¹QiÀëÁ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//0KZDm90MD@0MzAw6vNoARB9uOLz6cOP//wZcJakpwRmZaVzGAA)

`1` instead of `R`, `0` instead of `l`.

I'm new to this language, would appreciate if anyone could give me tips.

```
²³F1¹QiRë0¹QiÀëÁ
²³               # Push the second and third inputs.
  F              # Do the following [third input] times:
   1¹Qi          # If the first input is equal to 1,
       R         # Reverse (at this point, the second input will be at the top of the stack).
        ë0¹Qi    # Else-if the first input is equal to 0,
             À   # Shift left.
              ëÁ # Else shift right.
```

Comment: [`F²iRë²_iÀëÁ` (11 bytes)](https://tinyurl.com/wk5bmxk) with the input-order changed a bit. Some tips: 1) Input is implicitly if nothing is on the stack, so you can take advantage of that. This is what I did with the initial `F` without explicitly using the first input, and I do the same with the `R`/`À`/`Á` and the third implicit input-string. 2) Only `1` is truthy in 05AB1E, so no need to explicitly do the `1Q` check. Simply `²i` is therefore enough to check if this second input-integer is exactly `1`. As for the `²_i`, the `_` is a builtin to check if an integer is exactly `0`.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 72 bytes

```c
j;f(char*s,z,i,t){for(j=0;j<z;++j)putchar(s[i?(z+t*i+j)%z:t%2?z+~j:j]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bczLCsIwEIXhfZ9iDIiJHaFVvGCU4s69S3FRetEJNZV2RIzoq9foUtwN5/uZbJRVqT12ndGlzE5pM2zRISGrR1k30qwjbVZOh6FRlyt/AtnuKZEu5CH5se@W3B8nLnyZpTko/ezIMpxTsiDVIyil2Na3/N4TOEOIEGKlA/@olUL4y3NRVfVW4BRhFP9hLvLdiUqBc48Ik19v7YCBONmcU0f2iEAC48W3XfiiKfjaWIh08Oze)

Input as: char* , length, instruction(r=-1 , R=0 , l =1), times

Loop into input string using a shifted index with modulo `i?(z+t*i+j)%z` or a `length - index -1` for reverse

Answer (score 2):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 32 bytes

```
pe{{so}{<-}{SO}{rt}{1}{RT}}cnjE!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/ILW6uji/ttpGt7Y62L@2uqikttqwtjoopLY2OS/LVfH/fyWP/PKUSiUFQwUlJ0clAA)

Takes arguments as: `"StringToMod" N "Op"`
Where op is a reverse ordered string for reverse, a string in order for rotate right and anything else for rotate left, other short options or `op` could be space character, alpha character, other. If those are unacceptable input add 4 bytes for `{'R==}` & `{'r==}` as conditions.

```
pe         # Push inputs to stack
{
 {so} {<-} # If sorted push reverse
 {SO} {rt} # If reverse-sorted push rotate right
 {1}  {RT} # Else push rotate left
}cn        # Condition on op
jE!        # Evaluate N times
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
Ḣ⁾lRi‘ịUṛ¡ṭṙN,$}¥ɗ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATwAw/9qZWxsef//4bii4oG@bFJp4oCY4buLVeG5m8Kh4bmt4bmZTiwkfcKlyZf///9sSGVsbG8gd29ybGQh/zU)

A dyadic link taking a Jelly string prepended with the instruction as its left argument (e.g. `RHello world`) and the integer as its right argument. Returns a Jely string.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>27</s> 25 bytes

```
≔×⌕RrηＩζδＦ×¬δＩζ≦⮌θ⭆θ§θ⁻κδ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYyxCsIwFEX3fEXo9AJxcO5UBNGhRao/EJpnG4yJfS8W8edjCh28y73DuWeYDA3R@JwbZjcGuLknMhxdsFD1VGk5KS0PhhN8VVlW1eIeSW5cFxPYP0DJ1rw2U48LEqOWc/lcyIUE11RqLAjMWjbpHCx@1tm68GZ4rPqSOmf0Pp4EiX3eLf4H) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔×⌕RrηＩζζ
```

Convert the third input to integer, then multiply it by the index of the second input in `Rr`. This leaves it zero if the second input is `R` and unchanged if it is `r` but it negates the third input if the second input is anything else.

```
Ｆ×¬δＩζ≦⮌θ
```

If the third input is now zero then reverse the first input the original number of times.

```
⭆θ§θ⁻κζ
```

Shift the first input rightwards by the third input.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 38 bytes

```
J.zKs@J2A<J2?qHd_FGK?qHN+>GK<GK+>KG<KG
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/30uvyrvYwcvI0cbLyL7QIyXezd0bSPtp27l727h7a9t5u9t4u///X5ynXqKQWWLvmJtYlZmXrqOQyaXEZfEvv6AkMz@v@L@ubkpqUmk6AA)

This is a quite naive strategy but it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Input is taken on three lines: the first is the input, second is the operation, third is the count.

Substitute `R` for  (space).
Substitute `l` for `"` (double quote).

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 74 bytes

```javascript
i=>n=>g=a=>n--?g(a.map((_,p)=>a[(i-1?i-2?L+p-1:p+1:L+~p)%L],L=a.length)):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rc69DoIwFEDh3afoYrg32MbqRlKIO29gjLliqUXsrYC/g6@O7o46ne3LaehKfdX5OMjAezvWZvQmDyZ3hj6VsnBA6kQRYDuLaHJag5e68HJRlGmUOoupzsr0FXFabmalIdXa4IYDYkZjxaHn1qqWHdSgEfQcYa2USlbifPHVUew6vgVR8100l1PsBV9tJ4aDFS09H2LPTiUbVA37AEmCOPkW9V/Fxd8fl7@L4xs)

Input `i` (instruction, 1 = Reverse, 2 = Left, 3 = Right), `n` (times), `a` (array of characters).

Output array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `D`, 11 bytes

```
:[‛ǔǓiĖ|_(Ṙ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJEIiwiIiwiOlvigJvHlMeTacSWfF8o4bmYIiwiIiwiMlxuMVxuZWxsb0giXQ==)

Uses `0` for reverse, `1` for shift left, and `2` for shift right.